# How to dynamically bind parent element

Tags: silverlight, binding

I'm dynamically creating multiple expandable panel in silverlight. Every panel contains textbox. I need to bind this `textbox` to parent expandable panel `header` property.

How to do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Textbox.Text="{Binding Path=Header RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode="FindAncestor" AncestorType="{x:Type ExpandablePanel}}}"/>
```

Comment: I'm working on silverlight. FindAncestor & AncestorType not found on silverlight.

Comment: @ebattulga: Sorry, I guess you need to set up the Binding to use the x:Name of the ExpandablePanel: {Binding Path=Header ElementName=panel1} etc.
If you create the panels by template you can use the TemplatedParent mode of the RelativeSource.